# Array returning Undefined because of asynchrony

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am accessing the API Trello, but I came across the following problem:

Trello access the information, getting the id of each existing row, the code is as follows:

```
var x;  
var numberCardsByList = [];

trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of list: " + data.length);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        x = data[i];
        findNumberCards(x);
    }
});
```

As you can see, after getting the size, I walk all these queues with is, within the loop, attach each row in a variable x and call a function that aims to get the number of cards that queue. The code for the number of cards is as follows:

```
function findNumberCards(x){
    trello.get("/1/lists/"+x.id+"/cards", function(err, dados){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Name List: " + x.name + " have " + dados.length + " cards");
        numberCardsByList[x.name] = dados.length;
    });
}
```

Until then all right, but when I try to access the vector `numberCardsByList` after the end of the search in Trello, it returns undefined:

```
var x;  
var numberCardsByList = [];

trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Quantidade de Filas: " + data.length);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        x = data[i];
        findNumberCards(x);
    }
});
console.log(numberCardsByList);
```

I am aware that it is because of asynchrony, however, can not solve.

Comment: Please show an example of your code in a more complete way.. what i think is happening is you are first calling  `/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all` then in the callback your calling another function that does async operation, and after that function you do something else correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes is correct, as I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing has been solved many times before. If you want to know more, search for the keyword *"Promise"*. If you're familiar with jQuery, try and look up: `$.whenAll`, `$.ajax().done`, `$.ajax().always`, etc.

If you want to come up with a light weight solution yourself, here's a pointer:

By the time you get to your `console.log(numberCardsByList)`, your requests triggered by `findNumberCards` haven't yet completed, making the `Array` empty. You'll need to make sure you know when all `findNumberCards` requests have completed and *then* log them. Alternatively, you could log them *every time one of them completes*.

There are roughly two approaches:

1. Keep track of your open requests and call a function when a request is handled.
2. Observe your `numberCardsByList` object and call a function whenever items are added (you won't know if they were added async or synchronously)

I'd suggest going with the first approach. Check out this example code and the comments:

```js
var numberCardsByList = {};

// This array will store the url for every open request
var openRequests = [];

var removeRequest = function(url) {
  var index = openRequests.indexOf(url);
  if (index === -1) return;

  // Remove url from array
  openRequests = openRequests
    .slice(0, index)
    .concat(openRequests
      .slice(index + 1));
};

// This will be called whenever one request completes
var onComplete = function(url) {
  removeRequest(url);
  
  // When all have completed, we can call our callback
  if (openRequests.length === 0) {
    onAllComplete();
  }

});

// This will be called when there are no open requests left
var onAllComplete = function(data) {
  console.log(numberCardsByList);
}


trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of list: " + data.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    x = data[i];
    findNumberCards(x);
  }
});


function findNumberCards(x) {
  var url = "/1/lists/" + x.id + "/cards";
  
  // Before we make the request, we register it:
  openRequests.push(url);

  trello.get(url, function(err, dados) {
    numberCardsByList[x.name] = dados.length;
    
    // When it is completed, we call onComplete
    onComplete(url);
  });
};
```

Note that this `onAllComplete` isn't 100% safe: it might be called multiple times if a request finishes before the next one is started.

**Concluding:**

If you can, I'd use a library to handle promises. If you want to try and build something yourself, you could try and keep track of the requests and execute a callback when they've all completed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind my above code most likely wont work for you as i dont know whats going on in your code so this is an example / explanation how to deal with your problem.

Since you are unfamiliar with async operation i will assume you dont have a prior knowledge of promises and therefore give you a less optimal solution - however promises are alot better and you should defintely learn them.

You need to execute sequence procedures inside the result of the async code.

First you'll create a function for the second operation for example:

```
function numberCardsByList (param1,param2){.....}
```

You will then change fineNumberCards to also accept a callback:

```
function findNumberCards(x, callback){
    trello.get("/1/lists/"+x.id+"/cards", function(err, dados){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Name List: " + x.name + " have " + dados.length + " cards");
        numberCardsByList[x.name] = dados.length;
    });

    // pass in any params you need.
    callback();
}
```

And then you will pass the newly created function `numberCardsByList` to `findNumberCards` or wherever you want it.
    trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Number of list: " + data.length);

```
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        x = data[i];
        // and here we are calling findNumberCards and passing in the callback..
        findNumberCards(x, numberCardsByList);
    }
});
```

That is generally how you will deal with async operation, you will pass a callback for the next operation to be executed.

**update**

here is an example of how this is done with another scenario just to demonstrate the point farther.

we start by getting user

```
service.getUser(userName, function(err,user){
  if(user) {
    // we get user picture passing getPictureSize as callback
    getUserPicture(user.picture, getPictureSize)
  }
})
```

we get the pictureURL

```
function getUserPicture(picName, cb){
  service.getPictureURL(picName, function(err, pictureURL){
    if(pictureURL) {
      // we then call the callback - the next async operation we want.
      cb(pictureURL);
    }
  });
}
```

we get picture size - which is the last operation

```
function getPictureSize(pictureURL){
  service.getPictureSize(pictureURL, function(err, pictureSize){
    $('.picName').attr('src', picName);
    $('.picName').width(pictureSize.width);
    $('.picName').height(pictureSize.height);
  });

}
```

I hope that clarify things a little.